# What's the difference between "Normal" and "Classic"?

Tags: shadowgate

What is the difference between Normal mode and Classic Mode? I initially thought maybe it was a difficulty setting, but after hemming and hawing over what to choose, I saw that the next game selection is what difficulty to play on. So clearly "normal" vs "classic" isn't a difficulty setting. What is it? What changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadowgate 2014 has 4 difficulty settings.

Normal mode is its own difficulty level, but Classic mode will prompt you to select a difficulty

In order from easiest to hardest, they are:

- Normal Mode (aka Novice)
- Classic Mode Journeyman
- Classic Mode Adept
- Classic Mode Master

Note that the latter 3 can also be played Ironman which disallows saving.

From the Steam store page:

> Difficulty Levels: Four different difficulty levels (from the novice to expert) that actually change the gameplay experience and puzzle structure. For the ultimate challenge, try Ironman mode that disables saves and requires players to finish the game in one try.

Having just played through the start of Normal mode:

- Your torch never runs out.
- Two of the mirrors aren't present in the mirror room.
- Only beneficial actions are highlighted on the action wheel.  This prevents you from killing yourself from taking the book in the third room, for example.

The game is considerably more forgiving in the easier difficulty levels... things that would kill you instantly in Master difficulty (such as using a sword on yourself) will prompt you several times before happening in Novice.

The harder difficulty levels also have more rooms and harder puzzles.

As an example of how the puzzles change between difficult levels, here's a vague solution for one of the early puzzles:

- Normal

  - Put in the code shown.
  - Place the gear
  - Press the button.
- Journeyman

  - Figure out how to turn on power to the puzzle.
  - Put in the code shown.
  - Place the gear
  - Press the button.
  - Figure out how to remove the gear because you only get one from the Crypt in this mode.
- Adept

  - Figure out how to turn on power to the puzzle.
  - Figure out how to remove the gear so you can see the solutions to the puzzle.

    - There are 2 solutions in this mode
  - Put in the first solution.
  - Place the gear.
  - Press the button.
  - Come back after exploring the first area that opens and put in the second solution.
  - Press the button.
  - Remove the gear because you need it later.
- Master

  - Figure out how to turn on power to the puzzle.
  - Figure out how to remove the gear so you can see the solutions to the puzzle.

    - The method to remove it in Adept doesn't work in Master.  Good luck figuring out how to remove it!
    - There are 3 solutions in this mode
  - Place the gear.
  - Put in the first solution.
  - Press the button.
  - Come back after exploring the first area that opens and put in the second solution.
  - Press the button.
  - Come back after exploring the second area that opens and put in the third solution.
  - Press the button.
  - Remove the gear because you need it later.
  - After you visit the area the third code opens, you'll need to return here later to switch back to the second code.  And then back to any code except the second code... you revisit this puzzle a lot in Master mode.

Comment: This is awesome info but this answers a different question (how difficulty levels work). My question was what the difference between "Normal" and "Classic" is, which is the option I got when creating a new game right before it asked me what difficulty to select. Initially I had thought those were difficulty options, but apparently they aren't.

Comment: @Sterno You don't get a choice of difficulty if you choose Normal.  I went and tested it to make sure.  Hence why there are four difficulties.